# Physical/Geometric models for Reals , of different Cardinality (Lowenheim-Skolem, etc)?

Tags: nonstandard-analysis, nonstandard-models

The Real line is a model for the Standard Reals. Are there also known geometric or other ways of representing models of the Reals of different cardinality, e.g., the Hyperreals?

Comment: What do you mean by "model of the Reals"?

Comment: I mean, all the properties of the Reals as a structure are verified, or in agreement with, the properties of the Real line. Let me think of more specifics to add.

Comment: It's worth noting that a hyperreal field need *not* have larger cardinality than $\mathbb{R}$. For example, if $\mathcal{U}$ is a nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$ the [ultrapower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct) $\prod\mathbb{R}/\mathcal{U}$ is a hyperreal field of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}=\vert\mathbb{R}\vert$. However, this doesn't make your question of how to "represent" a hyperreal field well go away.

Comment: So you mean models of the first-order theory of the reals. These are called [real closed fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field). The minimal example comprises the algebraic real numbers and is countable. The reals give you an uncountable example as does the field of Puiseux series over the reals (both with the cardinality of the continuum $c$). The Lowenheim-Skolem theorem supplies you with examples of arbitrarily large cardinality.